# Можно ли отключить отправку формы, но оставить валидацию(angular)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть форма, по кнопке подгружаю данные через ajax, но нужно проверить поля.
Как по феншую правильно сделать, чтобы обновления страницы не было?
Сейчас поставил type=button  и нет перезагрузки, но отключилась валидация.
Хотел вручную проверить form.$valid , но всегда undefined, а другая форма почему вообще в отладчик не видна, хотя абсолютно одинаковые.

Форма, если в метод отдать саму форму, то тоже пусто.

```
<div ng-controller="spListCtrl as MyList">
<form name="newForm" id="newForm">

            <fieldset>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">

                    <tr>
                        <td ><input type="text" name="title" ng-model="MyList.newitem.Title" required placeholder="Введите фамилию"/></td>
                        <td ><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="MyList.newitem.FirstName"  placeholder="Введите имя" required/></td>
                        <td ><input type="text" name="mail" ng-model="MyList.newitem.Email" required  placeholder="Введите Email"/></td>
                        <td ><input type="text"  name="phone" ng-model="MyList.newitem.CellPhone" required  placeholder="Введите телефон"/></td>
                        <td ><button type="submit"  ng-click="AddItem()"> Добавить</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
```

И вообще, заменить `ng-click` по кнопке на `ng-submit` формы.

Comment: Изначально так и было, но по ng-submit почему-то в метод даже не заходит ."$event.preventDefault()" отменяет отправку, как надо, но убивает валидацию .

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov, сделай небольшой пример на jsfiddle, я его поправлю.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tmdmx7y4/

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov, https://jsfiddle.net/tmdmx7y4/1/ И вообще, я ж работающий пример просил, а не набор шмотков кода без ангуляра и с синтаксическими ошибками.

Comment: Полный пример почему-то не работает в Jsfiddle, как у меня. У меня все это в SharePoint. Сейчас еще раз попробую

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov, я тебе уже сделал работающий пример в jsfiddle с исправлением того, о чём ты спросил. Что не устраивает?

Comment: не работает. У меня получилось похожее сделать и на тесте работало как надо, http://plnkr.co/edit/lCS8a9aWUEythMIFTjZC изменение конструкции модуля и контроллера помогли, но в проекте не сработало. По какой-то причине обработчик не вызывается

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov, всё там работает.

Comment: увы нет( В примерах работает, а у меня обработчик не вызывается

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov, потому что ты намешал  скоуп с инстансом контроллера и у тебя просто нет нужной функции?

Comment: нет, я scope почти не использую. Все решилось, прям жаль что целый день потратил. все было правильно с самого начала, просто виноват действительно SharePoint, достаточно было поставить </form> перед моей разметкой. Извините что повыносил мозг) Вот решение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020390/using-angular-submit-button-causes-redirect-instead-of-calling-function-in-share

Comment: @AlexeyKleandrov, [рекомендуется](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/178988) в вопрос добавлять ссылку на вопрос на другом языке.

Comment: это не мой вопрос, нашел когда искал конфликты SP<>Angular